# Execute a SQL query With Anchor Tag

Tags: php, html, sql, anchor

please help to solve this issue,

I have a Anchor Tag in my page.

i want to perform a SQL UPDATE query when users click the anchor tag, how can i do that without reloading the page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried ? using jquery binding an onclick event that creates an ajax request ?

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: i don't have any clear idea on how to write the code for this... i should use ajax with jquery or is there any other way in php itself. plz suggest me with the concept i will come up with the code..

Answer (score 2):

if this is your anchor :

```
<a href="#a" id="myAnchor">myAnchor</a>
```

then you could use jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myAnchor').click(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: "sendWhatEverYouWant.php",
data:{ varName: $(this).attr('id')}
);
});
</script>
```

check the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

in the php you handle the request as an normal get request using:

```
$_GET['varName']
```